# Correlate two DataFrames based on a key, and a timespan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, timespan

I work in medicine and I am trying to identify events that happen within a time span after an event.  For example if a patient is admitted to the hospital, I want to be able to find out what changes happened within a time span. So say from the time they were discharged, and before their follow up visit.

I have two DataFrames that have an identifier for the person.

For this example we will say the first DataFrame is details containing the person's identifier and two datetime columns that I want to be able to use to filter our another DataFrame with.

df_discharge

```py
         Person         DischargeDate              FollowUpVisitDate
0        P000001        2022-03-18 10:03           2022-03-30 14:00
1        P000002        2022-03-18 11:18           2022-04-13 08:30
2        P000003        2022-03-18 11:21           2022-03-21 15:20
3        P000004        2022-03-19 22:03           2022-06-30 11:40
```

The second dataframe has the same Person identifier, and the time of an event, as well as some kind of description.

df_event

```py
         Person         EventDate                  Event
0        P000001        2010-03-18 12:00           Perscribed New Medication
1        P000001        2022-03-19 23:50           Called 911
2        P000001        2022-03-20 00:15           Presented to ED 
3        P000002        2022-04-13 09:45           Medication Adjustment
4        P000004        2022-03-30 13:21           Missed Appointment
5        P000004        2022-04-01 15:33           Rescheduled
6        P000004        2022-04-19 09:33           Refilled Medication
```

I feel like there is probably an easier way to do this than what I am doing, but ideally, I would like to be able to identify what indexes from df_event share the same Person, and if the df_event['EventDate'] is BETWEEN df_discharge['DischargeDate'] and df_discharge['FollowUpDate']

This is how I have accomplished this in the past, but I am sure there must be a better way to do this.

```
def between(identifier, df1, start_date, end_date, df2, event_date) -> pd.Series:
    out_series = pd.Series(index=df2.index, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
    for i, row in df2.iterrows():
        res = df1.loc[(df1[identifier] == row[identifier]) & (df1[start_date] <= row[event_date]) & (df1[end_date] >= row[event_date])].index
        if res.any():
            out_series.loc[i] = res[0]
    return out_series

df_event['DischargeIndex'] = between('Person', df_discharge, 'DischargeDate', 'FollowUpVisitDate', df_event, 'EventDate')
```

Which produces:

df_event

```py
         Person         EventDate                  Event                        DischargeIndex
0        P000001        2010-03-18 12:00           Perscribed New Medication.   <NA>
1        P000001        2022-03-19 23:50           Called 911                   0
2        P000001        2022-03-20 00:15           Presented to ED              0
3        P000002        2022-04-13 09:45           Medication Adjustment        <NA>
4        P000004        2022-03-30 13:21           Missed Appointment           3
5        P000004        2022-04-01 15:33           Rescheduled                  3
6        P000004        2022-04-19 09:33           Refilled Medication          3
```

At this point, I can merge and analyze pretty simply, but I feel like this is not the way to solve this problem.

**Update:**

@amance's solution drastically improves upon my solution.

Examples using real-world data

Original Solution:

```py
%%timeit
between('Person', df_discharge, 'DischargeDate', 'FollowUpVisitDate', df_event, 'EventDate')
```

**199 ms ± 7.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)**

@amance's solution:

```py
%%timeit
#creating 'DishchargeIndex'   
df_discharge = df_discharge.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'DischargeIndex'})   

#creating a 3rd df rather than lose data in df_event
df3 = pd.merge(df_discharge, df_event, on='Person')

#keeping only pertinent cases
df3 = df3[df3['EventDate'].between(df3['DischargeDate'], df3['FollowUpVisitDate'])].reset_index(drop=True)

#producing same final format
df3 = df3[['Person', 'EventDate', 'Event', 'DischargeIndex']]
```

**5.95 ms ± 422 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)**

So, this is a 40x speed increase.  Thank you.

I have altered it slightly just to meet my own needs, and style.  This is my current final result.

```py
def between_new(identifier: str, df1: pd.DataFrame, start_date: str, end_date: str, df2: pd.DataFrame, event_date: str) -> pd.Series:
    df_temp = df1.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'final_index'})[[identifier, 'final_index', start_date, end_date]]
    df_out = df2.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'event_index'})[[identifier,'event_index', event_date]]
    df3 = df_out.merge(df_temp, on=identifier)
    df3 = df3[df3[event_date].between(df3[start_date], df3[end_date])]
    return df3[['event_index', 'final_index']].set_index('event_index')['final_index']
```

Thank you, @amance

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little faster.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#loading data
df_discharge = pd.DataFrame({'Person': {0: 'P000001', 1: 'P000002', 2: 'P000003', 3: 'P000004'}, 'DischargeDate': {0: '2022-03-18 10:03', 1: '2022-03-18 11:18', 2: '2022-03-18 11:21', 3: '2022-03-19 22:03'}, 'FollowUpVisitDate': {0: '2022-03-30 14:00', 1: '2022-04-13 08:30', 2: '2022-03-21 15:20', 3: '2022-06-30 11:40'}})
df_event = pd.DataFrame({'Person': {0: 'P000001', 1: 'P000001', 2: 'P000001', 3: 'P000002', 4: 'P000004', 5: 'P000004', 6: 'P000004'}, 'EventDate': {0: '2010-03-18 12:00', 1: '2022-03-19 23:50', 2: '2022-03-20 00:15', 3: '2022-04-13 09:45', 4: '2022-03-30 13:21', 5: '2022-04-01 15:33', 6: '2022-04-19 09:33'}, 'Event': {0: 'Perscribed New Medication', 1: 'Called 911', 2: 'Presented to ED', 3: 'Medication Adjustment', 4: 'Missed Appointment', 5: 'Rescheduled', 6: 'Refilled Medication'}})

#creating 'DishchargeIndex'   
df_discharge = df_discharge.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'DischargeIndex'})   

#creating a 3rd df rather than lose data in df_event
df3 = pd.merge(df_discharge, df_event, on='Person')

#keeping only pertinent cases
df3 = df3[df3['EventDate'].between(df3['DischargeDate'], df3['FollowUpVisitDate'])].reset_index(drop=True)

#producing same final format
df3 = df3[['Person', 'EventDate', 'Event', 'DischargeIndex']]

#output
>>> df3
    Person           EventDate                Event  DischargeIndex
0  P000001 2022-03-19 23:50:00           Called 911               0
1  P000001 2022-03-20 00:15:00      Presented to ED               0
2  P000004 2022-03-30 13:21:00   Missed Appointment               3
3  P000004 2022-04-01 15:33:00          Rescheduled               3
4  P000004 2022-04-19 09:33:00  Refilled Medication               3
```

Comment: This solution drastically improves upon my solution.